# Spring data + MongoTemplate - constraints on document won't affect inserts\saves

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I'm using spring data in a simple web application.

I have a simple document that has a unique constraint on one of the fields:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({ @CompoundIndex(name = "playerConstraint", def = "{ 'playerId': 1  }", unique = true)
public class InProgressGameRound extends AbstractDocument {
 //...
}
```

Problem is when i call the repository of that document with:
    this.repository.save(newRound);

where newRound.playerId is already exists in the db - i dont get any exceptions!
the program counter just moves on and it seems everything is alright even though the document wasnt really saved (because of the constraint)

If i try to manually insert into mongoDB the same entry - i DO get an error that says the constraint is not allowing he insert.

How can i verify if the save worked or not (with the repository)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Also I would suggest one variant. I'm not sure about your data structure but you can try insert document without "`playerId`". Mongo will automatically generate `_id` for each object for you which is unique and even more `_id` field auto indexed in mongo by default.